# Run two war instances in the same server.xml config

Tags: spring-boot, websphere-liberty, websphere-8

I've generated two instances of Spring Boot (1.5.10.RELEASE) (war) with different properties (DB),
My question is about to run those two instances with same port but with different context in WebSphere Liberty Core 8.5 ?

My server.xml :

```
<httpEndpoint id="defaultHttpEndpoint"
                  host="*"
                  httpPort="9081"
                  httpsPort="9443"/>

<!-- A application -->
 <webApplication id="A"  location="A-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war"  contextRoot="/interactioncorpcontext-a"/>

<!-- B application -->
<webApplication id = "B" location="B-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war"  contextRoot="/interactioncorpcontext-b"/>
```

As result :

```
**http://hostname:9081/interactioncorpcontext-a**

**http://hostname:9081/interactioncorpcontext-b**
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution is to create an EAR of two war modules  :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>ear</artifactId>
    <packaging>ear</packaging>
    <name>${project.artifactId}</name>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

        <parent>
        <groupId>a.b.c</groupId>
        <artifactId>AP00959-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.10-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
<!--        Project dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>a.b.c</groupId>
            <artifactId>CCS</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
              <type>war</type>
        </dependency>

                <dependency>
            <groupId>a.b.c</groupId>
            <artifactId>mael</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
              <type>war</type>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>



        <build>
        <plugins>


  <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.1</version>
        <configuration>
                <modules>
                        <webModule>
                                <groupId>a.b.c</groupId>
                                <artifactId>CCS1FRD0</artifactId>
                                <contextRoot>/interactioncorpcontext-ccs</contextRoot>
                        </webModule>
                        <webModule>
                                <groupId>a.b.c</groupId>
                                <artifactId>mael</artifactId>
                                <contextRoot>/interactioncorpcontext-mael</contextRoot>
                        </webModule>
                </modules>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>





</project>
```

Also to disable jmx endpoints :

```
endpoints:
   jmx:
     enabled: false
```

Comment: Why is this necessary? What didn't work in the configuration in your question?

Comment: because there are running on the same port !

Comment: Seems like the initial configuration would have run on "the same port" too.

Comment: yes, the main objectif here is to run two instance of DB on the same server with same port but with different context and of course different parameters.